# Check if user enabled closed captions in UWP Xbox app

Tags: javascript, uwp, xbox-one

Running into an issue in implementing Closed Captions in a Javascript UWP application. We use a manual Closed Caption implementation (because of cross-platform reasons).

I have implemented all the various user settings, like `ClosedCaptionSize`, `ClosedCaptionStyle` etc.

However, I seem to be missing the specific property or value to check if the user has actually `enabled Closed Captions` in his or her account.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.closedcaptioning) do not give any information other than how to style the captions. I had expected it to be present in the namespace of the aforementioned docs (`Windows​.Media​.ClosedCaptioning`) but that doesn't seem to be the case.

How can I determine if the user has enabled or disabled Closed Captions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I determine if the user has enabled or disabled Closed Captions?

There isn't a way to do this. Media closed captioning is enabled per video not system wide. Ref [How to modify the closed captioning settings on your Xbox One console](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/ease-of-access/closed-captioning-settings)

The app hosts the video if using a custom captions renderer is responsible for toggling on and off(offering UX). Built-in platform controls are bound by default to enable our system renderer.

If the app wants a different behavior we can override the button in XAML but for a JS app we will have to provide their own controls since that kind of selective extension is not part of W3C.